# Dropbox: How do I open a file without extension as a text file?

Tags: dropbox, text-editor

I have 1000+ text files without extension in my DropBox folder.

While looking the list of them by the DropBox app for Android, I touched one of them to see and edit but the app just said I should download any app to open the file and does not open it.

How do I open the files have no extension as a text file?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use another app to manage your dropbox that enables this functionality. I use [Astro File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.metago.astro) to generally manage the files on my device and this can also link directly to your Dropbox, Google Drive, SkyDrive, etc.

Astro gives you the additional option to "Open As", from which you can choose Text, Audio, Image or Video. Select "Text" and you get the usual list of apps that can open text files, including the DB Text Editor.

**UPDATE:** Unfortunately there appears to be a limit to how many files Astro FM is able to retrieve from a Dropbox folder. Somewhere between 1,000 and 1,100 files I get a "Connection Failed - Could not establish a connection to Dropbox" message when trying to browse the folder. 1,000 files (exactly) seems to be OK. There is no such limit with ordinary folders on the device.

[image: Connection Failed message when trying to browse a large Dropbox folder in Astro FM]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried Astro File Manager and the app allows me to open any file as a text file, as you said. But there is a problem. **The app cannot open my Dropbox folder which has many(1000+) files.** I just have reported the issue to the vendor and am waiting an answer.

Comment: @npcode: Yes, I see a similar problem unfortunately. With exactly 1,000 files in a folder it appears to be OK, but with 1,100 files it fails with a "Connection Failed" error!?

Answer (score 1):

Currently the official Dropbox app can open a file which has no extension with external editor. (I prefer VimTouch)

Comment: I have the latest version of Dropbox (2.3.8) and by itself it can't open an extensionless file - only by installing another app that perhaps registers this "file type" as a supported file type will it work. Ordinarily you get the message as mentioned in your question: "Please download an app that can open this file."

Comment: @w3d Probably you are right. I am not sure which app makes Dropbox app to be able to open extensionless files, but I suspect VimTouch.